# How can i use a Contains() in a YAML vso-pipeline demand?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, pipeline, azure-pipelines

I am setting up a build pipeline for one of my company's projects, where we need to be able to specify in the variables which build agent it should be run on. The problem is that we need the build to run on any available agent if no agent is specified, but vso only seems to have the `-equals` and not `-contains` which I believe we will need to accomplish this.

I've tried looking through the documentation, but have not been able to find any documentation except for the list of functions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=vsts) - but which only seems to work for setting up conditions.

This is what I have tried:

```
 pool:
    name: pool
    demands:
    - Agent.Name -equals $(RunOn)
```

The expected result is that it runs on any available agent if no agent is specified, and runs on a specific agent if it is.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `contains`. If you need it to run on any agent, then delete the demand when queuing the build. Or the opposite, add the demand when queuing the build if the default behavior should be running on any agent.

Comment: The VSTS visual designer does not show demands specified in the YAML file, so this unfortunately does not work. I've spent 13 hours figuring out a solution to this now, but still without luck. Do you happen to know if there is any other way to accomplish it?